# Java 8 BufferedReader lines() method prints different count number

Tags: java, lambda, bufferedreader, java-8

I have faced a problem to count line number using lines() method of `BufferedReader`. Following is the content of `test.txt` file.

```
1 Career
2 Filmography
3 Awards
4 References
5 External
```

Here is the source code to count line number twice.

```
  BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("test.txt")));
  long lineNo=br.lines().count();
  long lineNo2=br.lines().count();

  System.out.println(lineNo); // 5
  System.out.println(lineNo2);// 0
```

Here, I have question why second line of `lineNo2` print `0` instead of `5`? Thanks in advance.

Comment: As a general rule, don't expect a Stream to be reusable following a terminal operation.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The `BufferedReader.lines()` method returns a stream. Accessing the stream (eg when you perform a `count()` on it), will read lines from the buffer, moving the current position in the `BufferedReader` forward.

When you do a `count()`, the entire stream is read, so the `BufferedReader()` will - probably - be at the end. A second invocation of `lines()` will return a stream that will read no lines, because the reader is already at the end of its data.

The javadoc of [`BufferedReader.lines()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#lines--) specifies:

> After execution of the terminal stream operation there are no guarantees that the reader will be at a specific position from which to read the next character or line.

I read this to mean that there is no guarantee that it is immediately after the last line returned from the stream, but as a count consumes all lines, I am pretty sure it is at the end. Going back to the beginning of a reader is (usually) not possible.

If you need to do multiple actions with the data from the `BufferedReader.lines()` you either need to process to stream once, or you need to collect the data into temporary storage. But note that executing a terminal operation like a count of lines (or a collect) might never complete (eg if the `BufferedReader` is fed from an infinite source).

Comment: "Going back to the beginning of a reader is (usually) not possible.". If you have a big enough buffer you could just use `mark()`, Mark :P

Comment: @owlstead Hence my _usually_ ;)

Answer (score 3):

From the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#lines--):

> After execution of the terminal stream operation there are no
>   guarantees that the reader will be at a specific position from which
>   to read the next character or line.

`count()` is a terminal operation. Thus the position of the reader is unspecified after the first `count()`-call.

Comment: @BlackPanther Yes, unfortunately it does not explain the behavior above; actually, the stream *has* progressed to a position to read out the next line. It's just that 1) it hasn't got any more lines and 2) it has not been closed. Note that it says "a position" not "the start position", I think this comment is because operations on the lines may have concluded before everything has been read.

Comment: But that is no reason to down vote the answer. It can be clearly inferred from the javadoc quote that the first invocation consumes the data and can no longer be used. "After the terminal operation is performed, the stream pipeline is considered consumed, and can no longer be used" from [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#StreamOps](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#StreamOps)

Answer (score 3):

The java 8 API specifies [**here**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#lines--) that

> After execution of the terminal stream operation there are no guarantees that the reader will be at a specific position from which to read the next character or line.

So after you execute the `br.lines().count()` statement there is no guarantee on the pointer's location.

The `lines().count()` invocation consumes the data from the file and when invoked again without closing the stream. It cannot consume the same data again by invoking `br.lines().count()`.

Comment: I think it is safe to assume that a `BufferedReader` (or any reader or inputstream) will never go back to a starting position (except when explicitly requested with `mark(..)` and `reset()`, if supported); the warning conveys that the position might not be what you expected from the last line you consumed from the stream (eg immediately after that line).

Comment: @BlackPanther "So after you execute the br.lines() statement there is no guarantee on the pointer's location." Note that count() is the terminal operation not lines().